# Adding a namespace to root node is causing it to add the namespace to add the child nodes as well

Tags: java, dom4j

```
String retVal = null;
Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
Element documentRoot = document.addElement(LOAD_EVENT);
Element header = documentRoot.addElement(HEADER);
Element body = documentRoot.addElement(DOCUMENTS);
Namespace namespace =
new Namespace("", "http://www.acme.com/LoadEvent");
documentRoot.add(namespace);
```

This is causing the xmlns to be added to the header and body nodes as well. How do I only have the xmlns added to the root node which is loadEvent ?

Comment: any solution to this so far?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be confusing. When a document is represented as a tree of element and other node types, each element belongs to a specific namespace, independently of any other element node, even of its ancestors. This is true for all the "major" XML node oriented API:s (DOM, JDOM, DOM4J and XOM).

Since you created the LOAD_EVENT element to be in no namespace, but later added a default namespace declaration to the node, DOM4J didn't have a choice but to change the namespace for the LOAD_EVENT (this is where DOM4J allows a very confusing action, IMHO). However, the child nodes are still in no namespace (or the empty namespace).

When you later serialize the tree to XML, the default namespace declared at the root node muste be "undeclared" for each child.

My guess is that you want something like this:

```
    String NS = "http://www.acme.com/LoadEvent";
    Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
    Element documentRoot = document.addElement("load", NS);
    Element header = documentRoot.addElement("header", NS);
    Element body = documentRoot.addElement("documents", NS);
```

That is, every element belongs to the NS namespace.

In other words: in tree oriented API:s, an element node does not inherit the namespace of its parent. Each element must be created with the proper namespace, if it has one.